# right aligning rows of grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will take in lists of rows and print them out in a form of a grid.

I have successfully managed to transform the lists of rows into a grid format, but I am currently having trouble aligning the rows in a specific manner.

I came up with a algorithm, but I am not sure if this is a pythonic way.

```
grid = [[21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [21, 42, 63, 84, 105], [21, 63, 126, 210, 315], [21, 84, 210, 420, 735], [21, 105, 315, 735, 1470]]

# grid[-1][-1]always the largest number in grid
# p is the number of digits of the largest number

p = len(str(grid[-1][-1]))

manipulated_grid = '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in grid)
print(manipulated_grid)


# current output
21 21 21 21 21
21 42 63 84 105
21 63 126 210 315
21 84 210 420 735
21 105 315 735 1470
```

First objective is to space the elements in the first row. I plan on giving

```
(p - 1) * ' ' for the spacing between the elements in the first row.
```

For example, since the largest number is 1470 and its digits 4, I want 3 spaces in between the elements of the first row.

I tried using the regular expression module, but my effort turned out to be abortive. How should I approach?

```
# current output
21 21 21 21 21
21 42 63 84 105
21 63 126 210 315
21 84 210 420 735
21 105 315 735 1470


# 1st objective
   21   21   21   21   21
21 42 63 84 105
21 63 126 210 315
21 84 210 420 735
21 105 315 735 1470
```

with first row in line, now my second objective is to right align all the elements in the other rows to the first row.

```
# desired output
   21   21   21   21   21
   21   42   63   84  105
   21   63  126  210  315
   21   84  210  420  735
   21  105  315  735 1470
```

I have been trying to use the rjust() function as well, but I could not figure out how to apply the function to my case.

Comment: The [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) package is your friend! You can also do it with a `str.format`, but `tabulate` really does it all for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python >= 3.6 you can do this:

```
for row in grid:
    print(' '.join(f'{item:4d}' for item in row))
```

and (as mentioned in the comments) if you have an older python, you can use string formatting this way:

```
for row in grid:
    print(' '.join('{:4d}'.format(item) for item in row))
```

if you do not want to print the grid row for row, this will do:

```
grid_str = '\n'.join(' '.join(f'{item:4d}' for item in row) for row in grid)
print(grid_str)
```

`'{:3d}'` will reserve 3 characters for your integers and right-align them.
more info on python string formatting here: https://pyformat.info/ .

if you do not know the width up front, you can do this:

```
width = len(str(max(n for row in grid for n in row)))
fmt = '{{:{}d}}'.format(width)

grid_str = '\n'.join(' '.join(fmt.format(item) for item in row) for row in grid)
print(grid_str)
```

for more options i also suggest [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) (as in the first comment on your post).

Comment: the `tabulate` example is `import tabulate; prettyformattedgrid = tabulate.tabulate(grid, tablefmt='plain')`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist what if my spacing variable were to vary? If I were to put in grid as input and my p could be anywhere between 1 and infinite number? Is there any way to modify {item:4d} depending on my p? would {item:p} work?